# What exactly is a solar gravity well manouver and in what cases would it be helpful?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, orbital-maneuver, physics

In [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44223/12102) to the [gedankenexperiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thought_experiment) question *With current state of technology if we wanted how long would it take for newly launched probe to overtake Voyagers?* I've seen the term "solar gravity well manouver" mentioned as a way to go fast and catch up to the Voyagers.

If I come up to Jupiter from behind I can pick up some energy in the heliocentric frame via a gravity assist and thereby head out of the solar system faster. But I don't see the utility of heading towards the Sun first before heading out; after a decade wouldn't I just be back at 5.5 AU going the the direction and speed that I could have been had I swung by Jupiter a different way?

Comment: Maybe where isn't stated clear enough. It means "Oberth maneuver" at the Sun, wuth rocket burn at perigelium.

Comment: @Heopps: Would you like to write that as a proper answer?

Comment: @Heopps oh, that makes sense contextually, but I'm looking forward to finding out how it makes sense energetically, quantitatively. On an Earth to Jupiter ellipse one *loses energy* at Jupiter in order to drop closer to the Sun than 1 AU?

Comment: @uhoh well, the good question is - at what parameters "Jupiter + solar Oberth" is _better_ than "Optimal Jupiter grav assist"? I mean at what parameters the resulting escape energy of the former will be higher? The answer I would like to know myself. :) I'm curious is vis-viva equation enough to model both these, or more thorough techniques should be involved? The main parameters - fuel mass fraction and Isp, perihelium altitude, sunshield mass fraction.

Comment: A vehicle barely needs any propellant to escape the solar system at a very high velocity with this technique. A solar sail that doesn't melt during perihelion passage, plus perhaps a bit of propellant for attitude control, are all that are needed. See https://www.nasa.gov/pdf/740774main_NosanovSpringSymposium2013.pdf , for example.

Comment: @DavidHammen that whole thing is extremely cool, or in this case hot! I've just asked [Why put chromium on the back side of this JPL-designed solar sail?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/44230/12102)

Comment: Also known as the Oberth-Kupiter maneuver. https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/1244:_Six_Words (explainxkcd link because xkcd isn't mobile friendly)

Comment: It's angular momentum you have to lose to get close to the Sun, not energy.

Answer (score 5):

This is an [Oberth maneuver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberth_effect), getting the most out of your delta-v budget by adding velocity on top of an already high velocity.

Nowhere in the solar system does one achieve greater orbital velocities than during perihelion of a Sun dive, as close as thermal management allows. At that ~100km/s velocity, every km/s of velocity added corresponds to ~14km/s at solar system escape, or roughly what the Voyagers are travelling at.

This is *not* a gravity assist, in the usual sense, as a flyby of the Sun can not by definition increase heliocentric velocity on its own. It's a nice position to spend a propellant budget. Traditional gravity assists would still be useful for getting into the sun dive in the first place.

A related use of this maneuver is for solar sails, where near the Sun in addition to being a nice place to velocity also *is* the place a solar sail can gain the most velocity.

"in what cases would it be helpful?"
Pretty much never. While it allows our current propulsion technology to go a little faster into interstellar space, it's still too slow to reach neighbouring star system in any reasonable case. That thought experiment about retrieving the Voyagers is perhaps the only "practical" use case.

Comment: About the "pretty much never" part, would it be helpful in building a ~10 year New Horizons-like mission to Pluto that could enter orbit there? The payload would be a lot heavier with the extra fuel, would a 3rd state that could pass near the Sun somehow help in this case? [Was there any launch vehicle possible that could have been used for a heavier New Horizons with enough fuel to enter Pluto orbit? (adding ~10 years)](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/53878/12102_

Comment: @uhoh My gut feeling is that since you would have to use Jupiter or something equivalent to even get the trajectory started my *guess* (not rigourious) is that just going out directly is the better option.